# Generate X509Certificate from byte[]?

Tags: java, x509certificate

Is there a possibility to generate an java.security.cert.X509Certificate from an byte[]?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Sure.

The certificate objects can be created by an instance of [CertificateFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) - in particular, one configured to create X509 certificates.  This can be created like so:

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
```

Then you need to pass it an InputStream containing the bytes of the certificate.  This can be achieved by wrapping your byte array in a [ByteArrayInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am getting  "(java.security.cert.CertificateException) java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input" on the last line.

InputStream is not empty, but it throws Exception

Comment: Same thing happened to me at first because I wasn't thinking carefully about what I was doing. In my case it was because I was trying to do the above with the bytes from a keystore rather than the certificate in the keystore. Extracting the certificate from the keystore, getting the encoded bytes, and then working on those was what made this answer above work for me.

Comment: In my case the problem was that the byte[] was base 64 encoded... The error message was the slightly misleading "Empty input". Maybe it helps somebody sometime...

Comment: What about bytes[] from password protected JKS file? How do we generate certificate from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
X509Certificate certificate = signature.getKeyInfo().getX509Datas().get(0).getX509Certificates().get(0);

String lexicalXSDBase64Binary = certificate.getValue();
byte[] decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(lexicalXSDBase64Binary);


CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
InputStream stream = null;
byte[] bencoded = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(x509CertificateStr);

try {
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(stream);

} catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention base-64, and the initialization of `stream` is missing. This code will throw a `NullPointerException`.